# Dart subtyping and method arguments

Tags: oop, inheritance, dart, types, subtyping

I'm trying to understand how Dart type system works.
Here is a snippet:

```
class Base {}

class Derived extends Base {}

void f(Derived x) {}

void main() {
  Base x = Base();
  f(x);
}
```

At least on https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ this compiles and gives the following runtime error:

```
Uncaught exception:
TypeError: Instance of 'Base': type 'Base' is not a subtype of type 'Derived'
```

Obviously, method accepting ordered set can't accept just a general set.

Shouldn't this be something that can be caught at compile-time? Are there some compilation flags to set so that compiler can detect such errors?

UPD:
here is an even easier example:

```
void main() {
  num a = 2.5;
  int b = a;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are an open issue here about this behavior:
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/30052

If you want an error from the analyzer for this you can create a file called analysis_options.yaml in the root of your project with the following content:

```
analyzer:
  strong-mode:
    implicit-casts: false
```

Comment: Why thank you! For anyone else interested, please check out https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/31410 (quote: "I now strongly (pun intended) believe implicit downcasts by default is a mistake on the order of ever introducing "null" into a language.") and https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/192.  
The only minor question I still have is that replacing body of main in my snippet with just `f(Base())` doesn't compile even though it's a trivial refactoring.
I think this might be related to ["Exact types"](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33307), am I right?